# How to export multiple ES6 modules from one NPM package

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules

I've built a relatively small NPM package consisting of roughly 5 different ES6 classes contained in one file each, they all look pretty much like this:

```
export default class MyClass {
    // ...
}
```

I've then setup an entry point for my package that looks like this:

```
export { default as MyClass } from './my-class.js';
export { default as MyOtherClass } from './my-other-class.js';
```

I've then run the entry point through webpack and babel ending up with a transpiled and minified index.js

Installing and importing the package works fine, but when I do the following from my client code:

```
import { MyClass } from 'my-package';
```

It doesn't just import "MyClass" it imports the entire file including all dependencies of every class (some of my classes have huge dependencies).

I figured this is how webpack works when you try to import parts of an already bundled package? So I set up my local webpack config to run `node_modules/my-package` through babel too and then tried:

```
import { MyClass } from 'my-package/src/index.js';
```

But even this imports every single class exported by index.js. The only thing that seems to work the way I want is if I do:

```
import MyClass from 'my-package/src/my-class.js';
```

But I'd much rather:

1. Be able to import the transpiled and minified file so that I don't have to tell webpack to run babel inside node_modules and
2. Be able to import each individual class directly from my entry point instead of having to enter the path to each file

What's the best practice here? How do others achieve similar setups? I've noticed GlideJS has an ESM version of its package which allows you to import only the things you need without having to run babel through it for example.

The package in question: https://github.com/powerbuoy/sleek-ui

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'sleek-ui': './src/js/sleek-ui.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'sleek-ui', // NOTE: Before adding this and libraryTarget I got errors saying "MyClass() is not a constructor" for some reason...
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

package.json

```
  "name": "sleek-ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Lightweight SASS and JS library for common UI elements",
  "main": "dist/sleek-ui.js",
  "sideEffects": false, // NOTE: Added this from Abhishek's article but it changed nothing for me :/
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/powerbuoy/sleek-ui.git"
  },
  "author": "Andreas Lagerkvist",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/powerbuoy/sleek-ui/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/powerbuoy/sleek-ui#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@glidejs/glide": "^3.4.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the `main` (entry point) attribute in your lib's package.json? Check in your build. And how you are bundling your lib package?

Comment: The main property of a package.json is a direction to the entry point to the module that the package.json is describing. In a Node.js application, when the module is called via a require statement, the module's exports from the file named in the main property will be what's returned to the Node.js application.

Comment: Yes, the main property points to my index.js which exports all the other classes. I'm bundling the main/index.js file using webpack and babel. It's all explained in the question.

Comment: this might help you - https://www.danielberndt.net/blog/2018/you-might-not-need-rollup-for-libraries/

Comment: You can also at their build implementation  - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/package.json

In order to have shorter build size it better to do `import { MyClass } from 'my-package/src/MyClass';`. You can also remove src build packaging to shorten the file path.

Comment: Works for me, with a simple test setup (no webpack). So probably an issue with Webpack

Comment: @powerbuoy I would like to take a while to help you out. Would it be possible for you to share the code or just a simple reproduction? I guess it would help a lot to see the webpack config and other files.

Comment: @Abhishek well `sideEffects: false` sounded really promising as that solved the exact same issue in the article, unfortunately it doesn't change anything with my setup :/

Comment: @DawidZbiński the real package is this: https://github.com/powerbuoy/sleek-ui so you can try it for yourself. The issue is that `import { AnyClass } from 'sleek-ui'` imports _everything_ not just `AnyClass`.

Comment: Please post your webpack config here.

Comment: @powerbuoy I'm going through your repo. I wanted to know how you are publishing this package? using npm publish? or you are using the yarn link? or webpack's resolve aliases? And the only dist dir is a part of your published package?

Comment: @powerbuoy any reason to create only `umd` export target. I'm not sure but I think tree-shaking does not work with UMD. Use ES2015 module syntax (i.e. import and export). - https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/  Generally, as I have seen or followed you can build `esm`, `es` build using only `babel` (no need to use any bundler) and you can use `webpack/rollup(preferred for libs)` to create `umd` export. Then you need to add `sideEffect: true` for this lib in package.json of your host package where you are importing or using this lib.

Comment: @Abhishek because I just followed the documentation when I ran into the "MyClass is not a constructor" problem. What are you suggesting I change? Changing "umd" to "esm" does not work.

Comment: @Abhishek I haven't published the package to npmjs yet, I just install it with `npm install --save-dev powerbuoy/sleek-ui`

Comment: @powerbuoy I would suggest you, export `esm` and `es` build using `only babel` (no need to use any bundler like webpack) and you can use `rollup`(preferred for libs) to create `umd` export (if required). You need to export in esm or es to make tree shaking work.

Comment: If you have already tried doing this, Can you commit your code with these changes?

Answer (score 4):

> I figured this is how webpack works when you try to import parts of an already bundled package?

Yes, the way you've got it set up is importing every class in index.js, which is then transpiled into one file (if it's targeting ES5, which is most common*). This means that when that file is imported in another file it comes in its entirety, with all those classes.

If you want proper tree-shaking you should avoid transpiling it into a CommonJS (ES5) bundle. My suggestion is to keep the ES6 modules, either by itself or in a separate location from the ES5 bundle. [This article should help you fully understand this and has recommended instructions.](https://madewithlove.com/optimizing-javascript-packages-for-tree-shaking/) Essentially it boils down to setting the Babel environment using preset-env (highly recommended if you're not already using it!) to [preserve ES6 syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targetsesmodules). Here's the relevant Babel configuration, if you don't want to transpile to ES5:

> ```
> {
>   "presets": [
>     [
>       "@babel/preset-env",
>       {
>         "targets": {
>           "esmodules": true
>         }
>       }
>     ]
>   ]
> }
> ```

The article details how to set up 2 bundles, each using a different module syntax.

Also worth noting, and is kind of mentioned in the article as well, [you can set the ES module entry point](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_writing_dual_packages_while_avoiding_or_minimizing_hazards) in package.json. That tells Webpack/Babel where the ES6 modules can be found, which may be all you need for your use case. It seems conventional wisdom says to do:

```
{
  "main": "dist/sleek-ui.js",
  "module": "src/main.js"
}
```

But Node documentation has it as:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/sleek-ui.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": "dist/sleek-ui.js",
    "./module": "src/main.js"
  }
}
```

If I had time I would play around with this and see which works correctly, but this should be enough to set you on the right path.

---

**ES5-targeted bundles are in CommonJS format, which has to include all the associated files, because ES5 doesn't have native module support. That came in ES2015/ES6.*

Comment: I tried adding `targets.esmodules: true` and while that made changes to the built script, it made no change as to what was imported in the end. Importing one single class from `my-package` still imports everything. I also tried the changes in `package.json` (along with the other change) and that too didn't change anything. Well, adding `type: module` actually broke my build with "Must use import to load ES Module: /sleek-ui/webpack.config.js require() of ES modules is not supported." so I had to remove that bit. I'll have a look at the linked article.

Comment: Ok so the article actually told me to set `modules: false` (not inside `targets`) but that didn't work either... I think I'll just import directly from the source file and keep running babel through node_modules until we can use this stuff natively.

Comment: @powerbuoy Importing from the source file works. Maybe it wasn't clear from my post, and if that's the case I can edit it, but you want to import only the class like `import MyClass from 'my-package/myClass';`. A good repo example of this is [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es).

Comment: @powerbuoy Can you mark this as the answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score -3):

This is a valid use case. The ultimate goal being to do this `import { MyClass } from 'my-package'` but there's a cleaner way of doing this.

Create an aggregator index file in your `my-package`. Basically `my-package/index.js` and it should look like this:

```
import MyClass from './my-class.js'
import MyOtherClass from './my-other-class.js'

export { MyClass, MyOtherClass }
```

Then you can do `import { MyClass } from 'my-package'`. Easy peasy.

Have fun!

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing already, which I thought was quite clear in the question.